# What is the proper way of converting ordinal values to numbers?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have two painkillers and I have given them to two  groups and recorded how the pain level changed in three categories: "Helped a lot", "Slightly better", "Did not help"

Now I want to do a t-test and I was planning to convert each label to a number (say 3,2,1) and run a t-test on those numbers to see if any of the painkillers is significantly better than the other one.

Now I have two questions:

1. If I go ahead with this ordinal to number conversion, what would be the methodical way of doing that? I can think of 3,2,1 or 8,4,2 and so on
2. Is there any test that allows me to do a hypothesis testing without converting to numbers?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

1. Technically, *any* ordinal scaling will do, but you can't take the means (or do t-test).  1, 2, 3? Fine.  Also, per Stevens' ideas, 1, 2, 12o9101, or 1, 1.2, 2.1021.  This points to one of the problems with Stevens' classification. Many things are in-between ordinal and interval.
2. You could do a Jonckeere Terpstra test; this tests for differences where one variable is ordinal and the other is nominal or ordinal

Comment: Thanks Peter, regarding "Stevens' ideas" can you give me a little background, are you referring to a book?

Comment: @MarkSAlen That would be Stevens, S.S. (1946). On the Theory of Scales of Measurement, Science, 103 (2684), June 7, 1946, 677-680.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans thanks for the clarification. Seems like a great paper.

Comment: There are plenty of techniques that derive scores from data like this, e.g. correspondence analysis. But for the specific question you have, something like Jonckheere-Terpstra sounds a good idea. Note that S.S. Stevens returned to his classification again and again in his life and that there is statistical literature arguing that the Stevens doctrine is greatly overplayed. See e.g. Velleman and Wilkinson 1993 Nominal, Ordinal, Interval, and Ratio Typologies Are Misleading. American Statistician, 47, 65-72 and follow up later discussion in that journal and elsewhere.